# Removing item from serialized list not working

Tags: c#, list, serialization, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having a problem with removing an item from a serialized list.
When it comes to write on the file, VS gives me this message:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred

The operation that I'm trying to perform is to select an item from a list, show it in details in another frame (and this is working) and then give the user the possibility to delete this item. 
This is the code I'm using for deleting the item:

```
private async void DeleteRecipe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Do you want to delete this recipe?");
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(("Yes"), new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(("No"), new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}

private async void CommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command)
{
    if (command.Label.Equals("Yes"))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Recipe>));
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("recipes.json");
        IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        using (Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead())
        {
            myRecipes = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as List<Recipe>;
        }
        randomAccessStream.Dispose();

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Recipe>));
        StorageFile myList = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("recipes.json",
            CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream1 = await myList.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        using (Stream stream = randomAccessStream1.AsStreamForWrite())
        {
            myRecipes.Remove(recipe);
            serializer1.WriteObject(stream, myRecipes);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
        randomAccessStream.Dispose();
        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Recipe deleted.");
        await msg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

`myRecipes` is the serialized list and `recipe` is the object that represents the element of the list that I've opened in details.

I really don't know where I'm going wrong, and before I added these commands the app was working fine with serialization and adding items to the list.

Edit: also, if I put `myRecipes.Remove(recipe)` like this:

```
using (Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead())
            {
                myRecipes = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as List<Recipe>;
            }
            randomAccessStream.Dispose();

            myRecipes.Remove(recipe);

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Recipe>));
            StorageFile myList = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("recipes.json",
                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

and not in here like above:

```
using (Stream stream = randomAccessStream1.AsStreamForWrite())
            {                   
                serializer1.WriteObject(stream, myRecipes);
                await stream.FlushAsync();
            }
```

the exception is not thrown but it doesn't remove the item from the list.

EDIT FOR FURTHER CODE:

This is how I add a new item in the list:

```
 public sealed partial class AddNewRecipe : Page
{
    [DataMember]
    List<Recipe> myRecipes;

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Recipe>));
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("recipes.json");
        IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream1 = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        using (Stream stream = randomAccessStream1.AsStreamForRead())
        {
            myRecipes = serializer1.ReadObject(stream) as List<Recipe>;
        }

        randomAccessStream1.Dispose();

    }
private async void AddRecipe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


            String name = RecipeName.Text;
            String description = RecipeDescription.Text;               
            myRecipes.Add(new Recipe(name, description,ingredients));



            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Recipe>));
            StorageFile myList = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("recipes.json", 
                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await myList.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

            using (Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForWrite())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, myRecipes);
                await stream.FlushAsync();
            }
            randomAccessStream.Dispose();

            Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; //get current frame  

            if (frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                frame.GoBack();                  
            }
            Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStack.Count - 1);
}
```

I manage the ingredients in another method, here is not so important.
However, I also noticed something else: after I delete an item and it gives me

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.WEB.NI.DLL

if I try to close the app and open it again, it gives me the same error just when it tries to load the list, so I suspect there's a problem in serialization in general...?

Comment: Try using 'RemoveAt' method to remove any random recipe. It might be a problem with how your myRecipes and recipe variables are declared and constructed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understood your method: are you saying that I have to use "removeAt" passing the indexes of all the saved recipes?

Comment: No. Since I do not have your entire class to check where you have declared myRecipes and recipe, just a suggestion to try myRecipes.RemoveAt(0) and try to serialize the result and check if that is successful.

Comment: Hey I just tried your code in a vanilla Windows Phone app. Its working fine. Are you sure if anything else is causing error in your project?

Comment: @Mayank I've tried that but it gave me the same problem.
@Romasz I've tried your way, also I've modified the code and used `myRecipes.removeAt(index)` where `index`is the index of the element selected in the list, that I pass as parameter to my frame (I checked and the index is right). 
Now is giving me a different problem: the deleting seems to work fine, but if I try to add an element after deleting another, it gives me the serialization error. Should I post the "adding" code?

Comment: As for removing item I suspect there was a problem in Equal() method, but it depends on your class and so on. Removing at specific index or removing item by finding it in newly created list should remove the item fine. Yes you should post further code, especially show the error. If you won't add the item, does it serialize fine? Also remove those *Dispose()* after `using` - it's unnecessary there.

Comment: I spotted that you are disposing other stream, then it's necessary unless you also put that one in `using`. Put both - straem and randomAccessStream - in usings. So if I understand if you remove the line which adds new element, the list will serialize fine - is that right?

Comment: Yes, but now there's something else: if I enter for the first time in the application and the list is empty, I can add up to 2 element correctly (without trying to delete anything), but then if I try to add a third one it gives me this:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll `

Before I add the deleting code it was working fine

Comment: Have you tried to debug your app step by step to see what's causing this problem?

Comment: Yes but i couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: DOes that mean that adding 1,2 items goes fine, and third causes exception? Have you checked the file generated after every added item?